# Programmatically check a checkbox (usercontrol) withing a DataGrids (usercontrol) SelectedItem / Row WPF XAML

Tags: wpf, datagrid, checkbox, custom-controls

I have TWO custom controls.  First I have an checkbox custom control, myCheckboxControl, (simplied xaml below)

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControls.myCheckboxControl"><Grid>
        <CheckBox x:Name="chkboxList" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Checked="chkboxList_Checked">
</Grid></UserControl>
```

I also have a a custom DataGrid control (simplified xaml below) that contains the checkbox control in a DataTemplate

```
<UserControlx:Class="UserControls.myDataGridControl"><DataGrid x:Name="dgMyGrid>
<DataGrid.Columns>
          <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="tempCol" Header="Checkbox(L)">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <localControls:myCheckboxControl x:Name="controlList"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Then I have the DataGrid (myDataGridControl) in my MainWindow.

The question I have is that I have a Button on the MainWindow.  When that Button is Clicked, I need it to also check the checkbox within myCheckboxControl.  I can get the SelectedItem of the datagrid, but just not sure how to get my 2 level deep checkbox to get checked.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have already known that the checkbox is a descendent of a user control which is hosted on a datagrid row.

So you will have to resolve these 2 level boundaries by using a mediator property at `myCheckboxControl` to hold `CheckBox.IsChecked`. You can introduce a new dependency property in `myCheckboxControl` say `IsCheckBoxChecked` an use that in further discussion.

I am using another property called `Tag` which is a placeholder for any extra information one may want to add against a framework element.

```
    <UserControl x:Class="UserControls.myCheckboxControl">
        <Grid>
            <CheckBox x:Name="chkboxList"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                      IsChecked="{Binding
                                    Tag,
                                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource
                                        AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}
                                    Mode=TwoWay}">
       </Grid>
   </UserControl>


   <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <localControls:myCheckboxControl
                       Tag="{Binding
                                IsSelected,
                                Mode=TwoWay,
                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource
                                   AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}}"
                       x:Name="controlList"/>
        </DataTemplate>
   </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Thus when you programmatically select datagrid row(s) then corresponding checkbox on that row will get checked. Also when you check the checkbox the row will get selected and vice versa.

**Now if you dont want selection to take place upon checking the checkbox, you will have to introduce a `INotifyPropertyChanged` based notifiable property at row item level.**

E.g. if you are binding a list of employees to the datagrid then each employee class must have a settable property called "IsSelected". This class must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and should raise a property changed notification from setter that `IsSelected` property.

In such case the binding is changed to this...

```
            <localControls:myCheckboxControl
                       Tag="{Binding
                                IsSelected,
                                Mode=TwoWay}"
                       x:Name="controlList"/>
```

Let me know if this helps.